# Redirect Nginx Permalink?

Tags: nginx

My website got de-index by search engine and I want to redirect to another domain with different permalink search. Can you help me to redirect from:

```
http://www.old-domain.com/gallery-some-title-keyword/
```

to

```
http://www.new-domain.com/s/some-title-keyword.html
```

Anyone help me? My website is use nginx webserver.

**Update notes:**

1) Where **/s/** on permalink is first char from **some**. So, if old permalink is **/gallery-true-title/** should be redirect to **/t/true-title.html**

Comment: all links will go to the `/g` directory in the new domain ?

Comment: Sorry, I have update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following location in your old-domain.com server stanza:

```
location ~ ^/gallery-(.)([^/]+)/ {
    return 301 http://www.new-domain.com/$1/$1$2.html;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have update my question. Char g is first char on permalink.